# MySQL-Database no longer exists after switching between two docker-compose configs

Tags: mysql, docker

I have two docker-compose configs, each of them has his own database config. After shutting down the first and starting the other one, the database is always empty (not stored permanently).

docker-compose config 1:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    container_name: mysql_crm
    image: mysql
    command: ["--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"]
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: symfony
      MYSQL_USER: symfony
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: symfony
    networks:
      - db
      - crm
    volumes:
      - database_crm:/var/bundles/mysql

....    

volumes:
  crm_elastic:
    driver: local
  database_crm:
    driver: local

networks:
  crm:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 179.22.16.0/24

  db:
    driver: bridge
```

second config:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    container_name: mysql_website
    image: mysql
    command: ["--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"]
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: symfony
      MYSQL_USER: symfony
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: symfony
    networks:
      - website2
      - website
    volumes:
      - database_website:/var/bundles/mysql

....    

volumes:
  database_website:

networks:
  website:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 188.22.17.0/24

  website2:
    driver: bridge
```

Cannot find any wrong config part. Can anyone help?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you trash your container you lose the data unless you mount local volumes. Are you sure that `volumes:` directive is correct? They oddly use slightly different names.

Comment: I'd expect to see the volume mounted on `/var/lib/mysql`, not `/var/bundle/mysql`.  If you launch a different container mounting the volume, is there actually any data in it?

Comment: @DavidMaze you are right - after changing the mount path to `/var/lib/mysql`, it works.